# VSCode debugging Quarkus application using a profile

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, quarkus, vscode-debugger

I'm using VSCode to debug Quarkus app, it works fine with the quarkus tools. However I could not find how to apply specific quarkus configuration e.g. dev, staging or prod as they are defined in the application.properties file. Any idea how to start the debugger with a profile specified?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your question - I haven't found a way to start the process from within Visual Studio Code.  The method I used was to start the Quarkus application with the desired profile (your method may differ):

```
./gradlew quarkusDev
```

And in my launch.json file I added the following section:

```
{
  "type": "java",
  "name": "Quarkus",
  "request": "attach",
  "hostName": "localhost",
  "port": "5005"
}
```

Next I ran my "Quarkus" profile in my debugger and it attached to the remote process.  Note that this assumes you're running Quarkus from localhost and "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005".

Answer (score 1):

[Assuming you're using the awesome [`Quarkus`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-quarkus) extension in VS Code]. Let's say you want to create a new launch configuration to start Quarkus in a `staging` profile, while keeping the default launch config for the `dev` profile. In your `.vscode/launch.json`, add a new config:

```
    {
        "preLaunchTask": "quarkusDev:staging",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "name": "Debug Quarkus application [Staging]",
        "port": 5005
    }
```

This launch config references a new launch task (`quarkusDev:staging`) that you also need to create in `.vscode/tasks.json`. This one actually defines the specific profile you want Quarkus to start with, by appending `-Dquarkus.profile` to the command(s):

```
    {
        "label": "quarkusDev:staging",
        "type": "shell",
        "isBackground": true,
        "group": "build",
        "command": "./gradlew quarkusDev --console=plain -Dquarkus.profile=staging",
        "windows": {
            "command": ".\\gradlew.bat quarkusDev --console=plain -Dquarkus.profile=staging"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            {
                "pattern": [
                    {
                        "regexp": "\\b\\B",
                        "file": 1,
                        "location": 2,
                        "message": 3
                    }
                ],
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                    "beginsPattern": "^.*Starting a Gradle Daemon*",
                    "endsPattern": "^.*Quarkus .* started in .*\\."
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```